# ie6 Sliding Doors problem rollover

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, rollover, sliding-doors

I have an `<a>` tag which uses the css sliding doors technique to show the rollover state

```
a.task_link {
width:220px;
height:241px;
float:left;
position:relative;
margin-right:20px;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;



}


a#task  {
    background:url(/images/task.jpg) no-repeat;

    }

a#_task:hover {
    background: url(/images/task.jpg) -220px 0px no-repeat;

    }
```

The problem is with ie6 I get a flashing/blinking of the background image, any solution to this?

Thanks,

J.

Comment: I think it'd be a lot easier to help if you could provide us with a live working example. Can you link us to a page?

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative` or `zoom:1` or `overflow:hidden` or something that will trigger layout without breaking usability.